# Set Firebase init Directory for cloud functions

Tags: firebase, terminal, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm trying to set up Firebase cloud functions, but when I input `firebase init` into terminal, it says:

> You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory: /Users/username`.

How do I save the folder in my projects directory? I tried...

```
cd ~/Desktop/MyProject/
firebase init
```

But it didn't work. And Firebase documentation isn't very clear about this. All they say is this...

> To initialize your project:
>
> 1. Run firebase login to log in via the browser and authenticate the
>      firebase tool.
> 2. **Go to your Firebase project directory.**
> 3. Run firebase
>      init functions.

Any ideas? I feel like I'm missing something simple. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific about what exactly didn't work.  Was there an error message?  What actually happened?

Comment: @DougStevenson I think I saw the same question earlier today. The problem is in the directory, which is `/Users/username` in the feedback from the Firebase CLI while OP has `cd`'d into the project directory.

Comment: @nachshon: When I saw the same question earlier there was a comment thread where somebody was trying to help. Did you recreate the question? Or was the comment thread deleted?

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem.  All you have to do is:

```
1) locate the firebase.json file in your /Users/username directory
2) delete that firebase.json file
3) Now run the firebase init command in your new project directory
```

This worked for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread as I was having a problem initialising a firebase function directory. I am in directory `D:/dir1/dir2` but whenever I ran "firebase init functions" it came up with:

> You are about to initialise a firebase project in this directory: D:/

Found out there was a `D:/firebase.json` and `D:/firebase.c` from a previous bad install. Removed them and started the "firebase init functions" again to get the directory: `D:/dir1/dir2`

Comment: Note that its just not the root directory but any parent folder having .firebaserc file. If so delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Reseting auth work for me. Here is the command

firebase login --reauth