# Firestore emulator - Error occurred during initialization of VM

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I learn about Cloud Functions so I read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started and this https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure.

I run this in my project folder:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
firebase login
firebase init functions
```

I run this in my project/functions folder:

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

I code some functions.
I run this in my project folder:

```
firebase emulators:start
```

Everything is ok.
I want to use Firestore.
I run this in my folder projects:

```
firebase init
firebase init emulators
```

(I accept to use firestore)
And here when I run:

```
firebase emulators:start
```

I read in my console: **Fatal error occured:
Firestore Emulator has exited with code: 1**
and in firestore-debug.log i have:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

PS: I use jdk 14

Anyone know wher is the error?

Comment: These both errors indicate that there is something not correctly installed with your JDK. Considering that, could you please give it a try reinstalling your Java? You can download the latest version from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html).

Comment: I already download again jdk :/ maybe the Firestore emulator take the wrong jdk. But I didn't find any config file for Firestore emulator.

Comment: Thanks for returning. Could you please check the,, this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158010/firestore-firebase-emulator-not-running
)? This way, you can check if it's related to the simulator.