# How to resolve Firebase emulator Node version warning?

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

What is the correct way to update Firebase Emulators after upgrading your local Node version?

After recently updating Node, the Firebase emulator throws the following warning when starting up:

`Your requested "node" version "16" doesn't match your global version "18". Using node@18 from host.`

The emulators still run without issue, but I'd like to prevent the warning going forward.

So far I've tried:

- Deleting the `yarn/package.lock` file + `node_modules`
- Then (re)running `firebase init`

  - [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure): "This command starts a configuration wizard that lets you select emulators of interest, download the corresponding emulator binary files..."
  - Also suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158010/firestore-firebase-emulator-not-running)
- Then reinstalling the npm modules (i.e., `yarn / npm -i`)

Answer (score 1):

Inside the functions folder there is a `package.json` file with a declared "engine" version like so:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
```

This lets you specify what version of Node the code will execute as. See this link for more info about the `engines` property: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#engines

To suppress the warning you can specify a version that matches your current Node version or use an asterisk. For me it looks like this:

`node --version`

> v18.13.0

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
```